# Printers object in VB 6 not returning printer with special character in name

Tags: unicode, utf-8, printing, vb6

VB6 (not VB.Net or VBScript)

I'm using the `Printer` object and recently found that some printers
are not being returned if the name has certain characters.

In VB6 it would be something like:

```
Dim pr  As Printer
For Each pr In Printers
    MsgBox pr.DeviceName
Next pr
```

I can easily rename any printer in Windows (any OS version) and
make it fail.

I suspect it's related to a UTF-8/Unicode issue, but I don't know how to resolve it.

For example, this printer name works fine: `"MyPrinter 1"`, but this does not: `"MyPrinter 1 ę"`.

How can I get the `Printer` when the name has a non-standard (for US English anyway) character?

**EDIT:**
I've found this code to access the printers, and it will correctly return all of them, even with special characters.

However, I don't know how to either:

1) Use the object for printing (as I would with a Printers object)

2) Or set a Printer object to the returned object from WMI

(FYI - The InkEdit control will correctly show the special characters without any Unicode wrangling - I'm using for display purposes only.)

```
Dim strComputer As String
Dim objWMIService As Object

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
                                  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Printer")

Dim myPrinter As Printer
Dim junk As String
For Each objprinter In colInstalledPrinters
    List1.AddItem objprinter.Name & " --- " & objprinter.ShareName & " --- " & objprinter.ServerName
    InkEdit1.Text = InkEdit1.Text & objprinter.Name & " --- " & objprinter.ShareName & " --- " & objprinter.ServerName & vbNewLine
    If InStr(1, objprinter.Name, "HP") > -1 Then
        myPrinter = objprinter.
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: [WMI](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?518105-Printers-collection-for-VB6-not-working-anymore&p=2041667#post2041667) should get the list but this might not be so helpful, depending on what you need from the Printer object.

Comment: Do you mean that certain characters make a printer not show up in the Printers collection at all? I think VB6 only [prints to the default printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa267233%28v%3dvs.60%29); if the printer with those characters is the default, can you print to it from within VB6?

Comment: You can indeed select a printer other than the default printer, I do it in my accounting software.  I'm not sure if it helps in this case, but what I do is read the printers into an array and populate comboboxes with the descriptions.  The only problem I ever have with my particular setup is if existing printers are removed from Windows, they might still be "selected" in my software unless my user(s) go in and select a different printer from the list.  It doesn't matter what they're called, but perhaps, as hinted, adding special characters excludes them from the list completely?

Comment: Adding a special character to the name (of any printer) will prevent it from being available when using the Printers object/collection.  You can try it easily by changing a single character in the name of an existing printer, then using the 4 lines of code from my post.